# SQLAlchemy before_execute and bound parameters

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a function that I've added as a before_execute callback for SQLAlchemy, like so:

```
event.listen(self.app_engine, "before_execute", self.before_exec)
```

In this callback I'm trying to extract the string representation of the statement that is about to be executed.  I've learned that this is not exactly trivial -- the trouble seems to come from ORM based queries as opposed to core queries, which are working.

When compiling ORM based queries I run into errors like the following:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: Bind parameter 'widget_id' without a renderable value not allowed here.
```

The multiparams argument to before_execute is populated for an ORM query, but not for a core query.  So I attempted the following:

```
clauseelement.values(**multiparams[0][0]).compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True})
```

But unfortunately that just results in:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: Unconsumed column names: widget_id
```

I can't quite get my head around how parameters are stored or processed, especially when you layer in the ORM.  I've read through some of the SQLAlchemy source and anything I can find online, but haven't had a whole lot of luck.

Here's the larger context of the code that's not working:

```
def before_exec(self, conn, clauseelement, multiparams, params):
    if not isinstance(clauseelement, (dml.Delete, dml.Update)):
        return

    query = select([clauseelement.table])
    if clauseelement._whereclause is not None:
        query = query.where(clauseelement._whereclause)

    stmt_redo = clauseelement.compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True})
```

The core style query that does work:

```
self.session.query(Widget).filter_by(name="Foo").update({"name": "Baz"})
```

The ORM based query that does not work:

```
        widget = self.session.query(Widget).filter_by(name="Foo").first()
        widget.name = "Baz"

        self.session.add(widget)
        self.session.commit()
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Why are you compiling the query in the event handler? What's the bigger picture here?

Comment: I'm playing around with the possibility of generating the inverse of any inserts, updates, or deletes that are issued and storing them in a log that can be replayed to redo/undo actions on certain entities.